# nginx failed (2: No such file or directory) as reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I set up nginx as reverse proxy for many virtual hosts, it works well, but for one.

it proxies the call to the actual server correctly, as well as it loads some images and others don't.
consider that the reverse proxy is nginx while the web service is hosted by apache.

this is the `error.log`

```
2023/12/13 11:20:25 [error] 1323621#1323621: *402 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/oslo.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.49.10, server: www.my-site, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2018/11/oslo.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "www.my-site", referrer: "www.my-site/"
```

```
##################
## plain http
##################

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gwww.my-site;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

##################
## cyphered https
##################

server {
    # SRV NAME
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.my-site;

    # TLS
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/websites/www.my-site.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/websites/www.my-site.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.my-site.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.my-site.error.log;

    # IP based access management
    #IP_CHECKallow                               109.115.186.2;
    #IP_CHECKallow                               192.168.49.0/24;
    #IP_CHECKdeny                                all;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    
    # CORS
    #CORSif ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    #CORS   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    #CORS   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    #CORS   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    #
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    #
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    #CORS    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    #CORS    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    #CORS    return 204;
    #CORS}
    #CORSif ($request_method = 'POST') {
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    #CORS}
    #CORSif ($request_method = 'GET') {
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
    #CORS    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    #CORS}

    # Security Headers
    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;                 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;        
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";      
    add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure"; 
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache';    
    # config to enable HSTS(HTTP Strict Transport Security)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' *.youtube.com maps.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.google-analytics.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com assets.zendesk.com connect.facebook.net; frame-src 'self' *.youtube.com assets.zendesk.com *.facebook.com s-static.ak.facebook.com tautt.zendesk.com; object-src 'self'; default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self'";

    # header and cache expiration
    expires epoch;                                    

    # security
    #Autenticazioneauth_basic           "Authentication required";
    #Autenticazioneauth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;


location / {

    proxy_pass                          https://www.my-site.portals/; 
    proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    proxy_ssl_verify                    off;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate       /etc/ssl/websites/
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth              2;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse             on;
    proxy_ssl_name                      $proxy_host;
  }

#location ~* \.(?:cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$ {
#      add_header Cache-Control "public";
#      client_max_body_size 0;
#      chunked_transfer_encoding on;
#      }

location ~* \.(?:woff|woff2|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|gz|swf|txt)$ { # testare!!
      access_log off;
      }

# CGI
# location /cgi-bin/ {
#   gzip off;
#   root  /usr/lib;
#   fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
#   include ./fastcgi_params;
#   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/lib$fastcgi_script_name;
# }

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    # include the fastcgi_param setting
    include fastcgi_params;
    # SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter is used for PHP FPM determining
    #  the script name. If it is not set in fastcgi_params file,
    # i.e. /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params or in the parent contexts,
    # please comment off following line:
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    location ~ \wp-login.php$ {
        allow 192.168.0.0/16;
        deny all;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/appname.sock;
        }
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    #fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/appname.sock;

}

location = /robots.txt {
   add_header Content-Type text/plain;
   return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
}
}
```

the resources are present on the server's file system but the first is found by the server and the second not.

```
root@wp-02:/var/www/dstorewp02/www3/www.my-site.# ls wp-content/uploads/2022/01/flag.png 
wp-content/uploads/2022/01/flag.png
root@wp-02:/var/www/dstorewp02/www3/www.my-site.# ls wp-content/uploads/2018/11/oslo.jpg
wp-content/uploads/2018/11/oslo.jpg
```

in the page code they are called as follows:

```
<img usemap="#flags" alt="flags" src="https://www.greencharge2020.eu/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/flag.png"
            style="z-index: 5;"><img src="https://www.greencharge2020.eu/wp-content/plugins/revslider/admin/assets/images/dummy.png" alt="" data-ww="['1427px','1427px','1427px','717px']" data-hh="['855px','855px','855px','430px']" data-lazyload="https://greencharge2020.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/oslo.jpg" data-no-retina> </div>
```

Any hint?

I'd like the reverse proxy to work properly, finding the contents.

Answer (score 0):

1. If Your static files are in `/var/www/dstorewp02/www3/www.my-site.` then tell about it using `root` directive.
2. Then You have to move proxy to portals to named location `@portal`.
3. Using `location /` tell to nginx to try to access static files in Your provided path and if file does not exist then to try to ask `@portals`

```
root /var/www/dstorewp02/www3/www.my-site.;

location / {
  try_files $uri @portals;
}

location @portals {
    proxy_pass                          https://www.my-site.portals/; 
    proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    proxy_ssl_verify                    off;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate       /etc/ssl/websites/
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth              2;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse             on;
    proxy_ssl_name                      $proxy_host;
}
```

4. fix typo from `server_name gwww.my-site` to `server_name www.my-site` - cause I suspect nginx goes to default location which is defined in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`  cause it cannot find `www.my-site` server block.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-site;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

or alternative:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-site gwww.my-site;
    return 301 https://www.my-site$request_uri;
}
```